# How to spread these cards evenly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[Codepen.io - full code](https://codepen.io/chionae/pen/PaRepY)

```
 <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <div class="side">Jimmy Eat World</div>
              <div class="side back"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/29841/jimmy.jpg" alt="Jimmy Eat World"></div>
            </div>
```

Although I'm using Bootstrap I can't spread these cards horizontally, and they keep shrinking (originally squared shape). What's wrong here?

Comment: Links to code pen must be accompanied by the code in the question itself - please use the snippet button and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the codepen you have a width of 150px set. You need to remove this to allow for a full width container.

All columns need to be contained in a row.

I have removed the width from the style, and added a row class to the card-container div. See here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MXVGVE

```
<div class="card-container row"> // Columns must be contained within a row class
  <div class="card col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="side">Jimmy Eat World</div>
    <div class="side back"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/29841/jimmy.jpg" alt="Jimmy Eat World"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Card 2...
  </div>
  <div class="card col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Card 3...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but in my actual code they are all layered. How to help it?
https://scontent-frt3-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/35896200_1729589803744794_7795307368123727872_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=ed820d62445c7847cbcad5db96b6d05f&oe=5BAD9F70

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: I'd like to have three cards in a row, but it's displaying like they all three are on a one place in the center.

Comment: Hmm. It displays correctly in the codepen. Stacking would be to do with the `position` styles. Try removing them and see if that works. Are you using the exact css in the original codepen? Is it possible it is being overridden by styles elsewhere in your script?

Comment: Yeah, that was the position! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

**YOU CAN NOT SET `col-..` without wrap it `row` div** 
Set `width: 100%;` instead `width: 150px;` to `.card-container`
and add `row` to `card-container`

```css
.card-container {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 150px;
    perspective: 600;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .card {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .card:hover {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  .card .side {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .card .back {
    background: #eaeaed;
    color: #0087cc;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<section class="section-heroes container" >
        <div class="u-center-text u-margin-bottom-big">
            <h2 class="heading-secondary">
                Choose your hero membership
            </h2>
        </div>

        <div class="row card-container">
                <div class="card col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="side">Jimmy Eat World</div>
                  <div class="side back"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/29841/jimmy.jpg" alt="Jimmy Eat World"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="card col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="side">Jimmy Eat World</div>
                        <div class="side back"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/29841/jimmy.jpg" alt="Jimmy Eat World"></div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="card col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="side">Jimmy Eat World</div>
                            <div class="side back"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/29841/jimmy.jpg" alt="Jimmy Eat World"></div>
                          </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: tell for more help